# allow php to access htaccess protected codes

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication

I try to reuse codes from my back-end across ajax, written in OOP pattern and protected witch htaccess . My problem is that I want to avoid the authentication popup for the front-end user when page is requested.

**Structue**

```
-admin
  -controllers
   --oneofmycontroller.php
  -models
    --oneofmymodel.php
  -views
  -index.php
  -.htaccess

-fontend
  -myphpfiles
    method.php// and here I try to access one of my controller to fetch datas
```

and the way how am I try to access

```
like /admin?controller=oneofmycontroller&action=methodToCall
```

the front-end codes are not yet OOP compatible

**Scenario**

```
vistor->access public page->public page calls back-end script across ajax to fetch data(which is htacess protected) -> if visitor is not logged-in sees a pop-up (and this one I would like to avoid but on the same time keep my back-end safe)
```

Comment: you are already logged in the back end (through HTTP authentication) and the client does further requests to the controller by AJAX... is this your case?

Comment: How should the backend differ between the two sets of requests?

Answer (score 0):

As /admin is protected by htaccess, you can not request it from outside. You can request a file in /frontend and include your controller from there.